# Plane image with alpha - clipping

Tags: transparency, image

So i have this scene where i have a plane with some smoke on it (image sequence with alpha).
Im happy with it but when the plane hits some geometry its some kind of clipping. Is there a way so i can slowy fade it out or something? Specially in this case the dunes are not "real" geometry (made with displacement mapping).

You can see it on the image 2 times. Right bottom and in the middle.[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot while in solid mode as well. So that we can know where the planes are. (I know that you probably mean that they are where the clipping thingy occurs. But the words are probably not the perfect ones coz you said hit, which I didn't understand, hence asking for the solid view)

Comment: Like i said those dunes are made with displacement, in solid mode you wouldnt see any collisions. But heres another screen with some markers. Those lines you can see there. https://imgur.com/a/kOa1slH